# Check if two elements have been clicked, and a value has been entered in a textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's a demo of what I'm talking about - http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewKosloski/qLpT9/

I want to execute code if "Foo" has been clicked, and a number has been entered in the input.. and if "send" has been clicked.

```
<h1>Foo</h1>

<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Enter in a number."/>
<button id="send">Send</button>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this, I'd appreciate the help on such a concise question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one: [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CJCqV/1/)

```
var send = document.getElementById("send");
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

var foo_clicked = 0;

h1[0].onclick = function(){foo_clicked += 1; };

send.onclick = function(){
    if(document.getElementById("amount").value !='' && foo_clicked >0 )
    alert ('poor rating');

};
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for helping me.  This works out nicely, but really isn't what I'm looking for.  

I'm trying to figure out the **BEST** way to execute a function when:

1. An element has been clicked. (For this ex. lets just say a word)
2. When a number has been entered in an input
3. And, when a button has been clicked.

The demo you have given me is close to what I want though!  Your's only works for the input and button.

Comment: Why did you except this answer then?

Comment: @MattKnowsTech - check in fiddle once more ,it is working for all three of your conditions. I'm incrementing global variable "foo_clicked" on-click of <h1> tag and placing this constraint in the button's click condition.

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement & taking some assumptions, try this way:

(This executes function twice - When there is a change of text or a click of the button).

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="">Foo</h1>

<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Enter in a number."/>

<button id="sendBtn">send</button>
```

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("amount").addEventListener("change",poorRatingCalculation);
document.getElementById("sendBtn").addEventListener("click",poorRatingCalculation);

function poorRatingCalculation() {

    var rating = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    if(rating=="poor")  alert("Poor Service");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wTqEv/

Comment: I should of explained this better, my bad.  I'm making a tip calculator, and this is what it looks like: http://d.pr/i/OkAY

I want to execute a function, if the first chicken leg has been clicked, a value has been entered, and the "Tip" button has been clicked.  I would like to run three different function hence three different chicken legs for: poor service, good service, and great service.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech - If that's your site, it has jQuery included, so why didn't you tag the question with jQuery. Was it to make us suffer ?

Comment: I want to see how its done with Javascript.  How'd you know its in jQuery?

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Besides, your statements & attempt don't seem to go together at all. How are we supposed to get a clear idea of what you are trying?? For example: where is the button in the question above?

Comment: I know, because the statements above, and the jsFiddle is a basic example of what I want.  I just posted the attempt because some dude yelled at me, and told me to put an attempt in..  I've been attempting this for hours. haha

Comment: I just viewed the source, but I guess I was a bit fast, as that's just the source of some lame ass image sharing site that I've haven't seen before, and even they used jQuery.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Please respect the time of people here. They are trying to help genuine people who put some effort into coding (not just thinking what they want) & get stuck with something.

Comment: Okay, sorry.  I'm just trying to make this simple as possible so people don't spend too much time on a simple question.  I'm new to Javascript, and I tried Googling it, and they said do eventListener.  I do respect this community and the great people who take time out of their day to help people like me.

Answer (score 0):

A better, self contained example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qLpT9/7/

```
(function()
{
    var clicked = false;

    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var send = document.getElementById("send");

    header.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        clicked = true;
    });

    send.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        if(!clicked)
        {
            return
        }

        // Foo has been clicked

        var value = amount.value;

        console.log(value;)
    });

})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/qLpT9/5/

```
function poorRatingCalculation(){
        if(myInput.value) {
            alert(myInput.value);
        }
 }

        var foo = document.getElementById("foo"),
            myInput = document.getElementById("amount");

  foo.addEventListener("click", poorRatingCalculation, false)
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the question, why is it the excepted answer?

Comment: Looking back the only thing I missed was one more condition for a button, which, before the question was edited wasn't mentioned initially and I missed it. Also I think the word you meant to use was "accepted" not "excepted". That being said mine isn't accepted and I don't think the down-vote is necessarily warranted. While not a complete answer, it isn't wrong.